# safe storage of multi-threaded web scraped data

Tags: python, multithreading, csv, selenium, queue

I am using selenium to do web scraping and then trying to store the data into a CSV file. I'm using a queue with workers so as to make the scraping operation faster.

However, I'm finding that sometimes one worker will be writing to the CSV, and then another will try to write to the CSV, resulting in data overflowing onto new lines.

Is there a safe way to have multiple workers all write to a CSV (or some other filetype) simultaneously?

Here is my worker and queue:

```
def worker():
while True:
    params = q.get()
    crawl(*params)
    q.task_done()

q = Queue()

for i in range(7):
    t = Thread(target=worker)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
```

each time 'crawl' is called, the worker writes a line to a CSV file and then closes the CSV:

```
data_fd = open('data.csv','a')
data_fd.write(line)
data_fd.close()
```

However, sometimes the following happens, when a worker tries to write to the CSV before another worker has finished writing to the CSV:

```
item_1, item_2, item_3, item_4
item_1, item_2, item_3, 
item_1, item_2, item_3, item_4 
item_4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take two different approaches...

1) You "lock" the file somehow - not necessary on an OS level (you could just have a monitor you acquire before writing to the file and release at the end, so that at any point in time, only a single thread holds the monitor and writes to the file).

2) You can split have a separate single thread dedicated to writing data to the csv. Your crawler threads scrape the data and append it to a queue. The csv thread keeps reading off the queue and writing the data to the disk.

Both approaches have their merits - the first one is probably less efficient, but easier to deal with. The second approach will require some thought on how big the queue can grow (in case csv writing gets slower that scraping) and also making sure the queue is drained before you quit the application :)